# syslog diff or comparison that reorders identical lines to ignore race conditions?

Tags: logging, syslog, analysis

Sometimes when debugging intermittent boot problems, it would be advantageous compare two exerpts from `syslog`:  One leading to a working system, and one leading to the symptom.  However, `diff` is not able to reorder lines to minimize the irrelevant differences and there are many such irrelevant differences due to parallel processes.

While it is true that boot problems frequently arise from race conditions -- in which case important information may be filtered out by such a reordering -- it is also likely the case that there will remain important differences proximal to the problem race condition.

Are there any such utilities?